# Finding phase is SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

In the aforementioned problem, i marked two lines in red. After writing $\sin \omega t_1=\frac{1}{2}$,how could they write $\omega t_1=\frac{\pi}{6}$?$\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ also satisfies the condition,so why did they ignore the angle in second quadrant? *Or is it a rule in SHM that we will take angles in the first quadrant only*?I have been puzzled at this for quite a long time.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second solution for $t_1$ is for when the particle is at $\frac{A}{2}$, but has been from $O$ to $A$ and is heading back towards the origin.

Comment: I didn't understand,could you elaborate why $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ has been ignored?

Comment: @madness yes, would explain what the question wanted?  It mentions it covers $O$ to $A/2$ in time $t_1$ and that seems like it's the first time it gets to $A/2$, that's why the first solution was used (probably), what did it ask for?

Comment: Ok but if it gets to $\frac{A}{2}$ for the first time,why should $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ be ignored?I didn't understand this part.

Comment: @ madness you need to explain to anyone reading, what the question asks for.  Then maybe we can help more

Comment: The question actually asks to find a relation between $t_1$ and $t_2$.That in fact isn't necessary to answer my question,that's why i didn't include it.

Comment: @ madness ok, the question means that $t_1$ is the time for it to first reach $A/2$, you are right there are other times, imagine a pendulum doing SHM and coming to the same place many times, but the question meant the first time.